# Не работает страна->город

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Был код типа страна-регион-город. Делаю без региона, не работает, в чем может быть причина, не пойму, подскажите?
Хотя при выборе региона, города, код абсолютно одинаков. Мне кажется, что не проходит ajax-запрос, но не разберусь, в чем причина.
Вот код файлов (выкладываю полностью):
**index.html**

```
<td><form action="#" method="get">
        Страна:<br />
        <select name="country_id" id="country_id" class="StyleSelectBox">
            <option value="0">- выберите страну -</option>
            <option value="1">Россия</option>
            <option value="2">Украина</option>
        </select></td><td>
        Город:<br />
        <select name="city_id" id="city_id" disabled="disabled" class="StyleSelectBox">
            <option value="0">- выберите город -</option>
        </select>
    </form></td>
```

**get_city.php**

```
<?php

include_once 'connect.php';
$city_id = @intval($_GET['country_id']);

$regs=mysql_query("SELECT name, city_id FROM city WHERE country_id=$country_id"); 

if ($regs) {
    $num = mysql_num_rows($regs);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $num) {
       $city[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($regs);
       $i++;
    }
    $result = array('city'=>$city);
} else {
    $result = array('type'=>'error');
}
```

**selects.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#country_id').change(function () {
        var country_id = $(this).val();
        if (country_id == '0') {
            $('#city_id').html('<option>- выберите город -</option>');
            $('#city_id').attr('disabled', true);

            return(false);
        }
        $('#city_id').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#city_id').html('<option>загрузка...</option>');

        var url = 'get_city.php';

        $.get(
            url,
            "country_id=" + country_id,
            function (result) {
                if (result.type == 'error') {
                    alert('error');

                    return(false);
                } else {
                    var options = ''; 

                    $(result.city).each(function() {
                        options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('city_id') + '">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</option>';
                    });

                    $('#city_id').html('<option value="0">- выберите город -</option>'+options);
                    $('#city_id').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            },
            "json"
        );
    });
```

**SQL**

```
--
-- База данных: `geo3`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `city`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city` (
  `city_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `region_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `region_id` (`region_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `city`
--

INSERT INTO `city` (`city_id`, `country_id`, `region_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'Москва'),
(2, 1, 2, 'Ленинград'),
(3, 2, 3, 'Киев'),
(4, 2, 4, 'Харьков');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `country`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country` (
  `country_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`),
  KEY `city_id` (`city_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7716094 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `country`
--

INSERT INTO `country` (`country_id`, `city_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Россия'),
(2, 0, 'Украина');

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы другие пользователи ru.so попробовали себя в роли синтаксических анализаторов кода? Не надо так! Укажите, для начала все сообщения об ошибках и желаемые результаты работы кода.

Comment: ошибок нету. Просто после выбора страны в поле город появляется надпись загрузка и оно остается не активным хотя должен высветится список городов соответсвующей страны. Пробовал в файле пхп вардампом проверить происходит ли вообще выборка вроде все ок масив есть но он почему то не доходит до конечной формы, может проблема в аяксе который я не очень знаю или еще где-то что то пропустил или недосмотрел

Comment: @ASYOU, в конце файла `get_city.php` у вас не видно вывода данных пользователю.

Comment: На сколько я понял там данные пользователю напрямую не выводятся а идут в аякс запрос который формирует данные и уже их подставляет в графу выбора города

Comment: В конце файла есть еще строка: ' print json_encode($result); ' но она на сколько я понимаю не влияет на дальнейший код просто вывод данных.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Мне кажется, что ошибка во 2 строке

```
<?php

           include_once 'connect.php';
**вот тут** -> $city_id = @intval($_GET['country_id']);

           $regs=mysql_query("SELECT name, city_id FROM city WHERE country_id=$country_id"); 

           if ($regs) {
            $num = mysql_num_rows($regs);
            $i = 0;
           while ($i < $num) {
            $city[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($regs);
            $i++;
          }
          $result = array('city'=>$city);
          } else {
            $result = array('type'=>'error');
          }
```

вы в переменную $city_id записываете значение $_GET['country_id'], а в запросе подставляете переменную $country_id

Comment: Да вы правы здесь ошибка, но это я уже недоглядел когда пробовал найти проблему и забыл исправить обратно перед выкладыванием сюда.. Но с country_id тоже не работает потому и стояло другое значение.

Answer (score 0):

Если попробовать так, что получится?

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['country_id'])) {

    include_once('connect.php');

    $country_id = trim($_GET['country_id']);
    $country_id = strip_tags($country_id);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $country_id = stripslashes($country_id);
    }   
    $country_id = htmlspecialchars($country_id, ENT_QUOTES);
    $country_id = mysql_real_escape_string($country_id);

    $regs = mysql_query("SELECT name, city_id FROM city WHERE country_id=$country_id"); 

    if ($regs) {
        $num = mysql_num_rows($regs);
        $i = 0;
        $city = array();

        while ($i < $num) {
           $city[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($regs);
           $i++;
        }
        $result = array('type'=>'success', 'city'=>$city);
    } else {
        $result = array('type'=>'error');
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;

} else {
    exit;
}

?>
```